# How to send messages to specific people in FireBase

Tags: security, chat, firebase

I am learning how to use Firebase and I'm really confused about how you would send a chat message to a specific person in Firebase. Basically what I want to do is have a 2 way chat between 2 people, but other people can make other chats with other friends also. Would you need a new Firebase for each chat?

Answer (score 6):

if A want to chat with B, A send messages (push) to

```
http://your-fire-base.firebaseio.com/b_id/ (B's channel)
```

with content

```
{sender: a_id, data: some_data}
```

B will subscribe to his own channel and filter the data based on sender.

Answer (score 1):

You can create nodes under a single Firebase to accomplish most scenarios.

In your case, I'd set up a hierarchy like this:

```
<root>

  Frank-Keiran

    <messages>

  Keiran-User123

    <messages>
```

Comment: This seems to be simple and quick way but imagine if you have 500 users who possible send message to each other then how many nodes will you end up.